# django-keycloak refresh openID connect .well-known error

Tags: django, authentication, url, keycloak

Hello everyone i really need help in a issue i faced while working on django-keyclock:

you can see here the documentation thet I'm following: https://django-keycloak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I did the initial setup and I setup for remote user , then i configured the server and the realms in the django admin panel and everything looks good. but when i try to Refresh OpenID Connect .well-known
I got this error in the image.
And i think that **/auth** is the problem because when I remove it I got a json response.

please if anyone can help me. and thank you in advance.
[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g09Jc.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv1E1.png